# How to return a boolean from a recursive function delphi/pascal

Tags: function, validation, delphi, recursion, parameter-passing

I am making  a program for learning purposes, which is why I'm using recursion to get more marks, although an iterative method would be more viable. I have made this algorithm to validate an email address to make sure it's in the format L@L.L. I am using recursion to validate each char in each instance. Once the recursion reaches step 6 then the email is valid else I would like the function to return false. Can someone please help me with this because my current solution has to use a global variable because otherwise each instance resets the local variable to false. I know the algorithm isn't perfect but I really don't want to use a global var as it will be part of a huge program.

A few possible solutions that I don't know how to do:
1. Pass a Boolean through each instance of recursion and set it to true in the final instance. This could be using by ref or by val somehow? And then pass it back through the stack 
2. Use a local variable local to the function and not each instance that doesn't change as you go through

Anyway here is the code:

```
var
  Valid:boolean;

Function ValidEmail(Email:string; I:integer; Step:integer):boolean;
const
  AlphaChars=['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'];
begin
    case Step of
      1:If Email[I] in AlphaChars then
        ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 2);
      2:If Email[I] in AlphaChars then
          ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 2)
        else if Email[I] = '@' then
          ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 3);
      3:If Email[I] in AlphaChars then
        ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 4);
      4:If Email[I] in AlphaChars then
        ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 4)
        else if Email[I]='.' then
          ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 5);
      5:If Email[I] in AlphaChars then
        ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 6);
      6:Valid:=True;
    end;
  if Valid then
    ValidEmail:=true;
  end;
```

Where email is the email passed from the main program, I is the count for each char and step is how far along the validation you are.

Comment: Note that, while `ValidEmail:=True` is a valid syntax, the preferred syntax in Delphi(as far as I know) is `Result := True`. I hardly ever see code using the `<FunctionName>:=<FuncResult>` syntax.

Comment: Ok thanks I did know that but I didn't know it was the preferred method, which I will use from now on thanks

Comment: I need to warn you that your code is going to incorrectly reject a large number of **valid** email addresses... You're ignoring many valid characters: `0..9,+,-,_` Even `.` is valid in the name portion of the email address, and is often corporate policy. Furthermore it seems you're only allowing a single `.` in the domain section. _One of the problems with trying to re-invent the wheel, is that sometimes you re-invent it incorrectly._ If this is intended for a production system, you would be better off not validating the address, rather than making it impossible to capture a valid one.

Comment: I've hopefully improved the algorithm below. It now works with other chars thanks for the help, I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok based on Craig's comment I've modified the algorithm to allow numbers etc.

```
Function ValidEmail(Email:string; I:integer; Step:integer):boolean;
const
  AlphaChars=['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'];
  IntChars=['1'..'9'];
  CharChars=['!', '#', '$', '%' ,'&', '*', '+', '-', '/', '=', '?', '^', '_', '`', '{', '|'
   , '}',        '~', '.'];
begin
case Step of
  1:If (Email[I] in AlphaChars) or (Email[I] in IntChars) or (Email[I] in CharChars)then
    Result := ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 2);
  2:If (Email[I] in AlphaChars) or (Email[I] in IntChars) or (Email[I] in CharChars)then
    Result := ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 2)
    else if Email[I] = '@' then
      Result := ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 3);
  3:If (Email[I]= '-' ) or (Email[I] in AlphaChars) or (Email[I] in IntChars) then
      Result:=ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 4);
  4:If (Email[I]= '-' ) or (Email[I] in AlphaChars) or (Email[I] in IntChars) then
      Result:=ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 4)
    else if Email[I]='.' then
      Result := true;
  else
      Result:=false;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is probably what you mean:

```
Function ValidEmail(Email:string; I:integer; Step:integer):boolean;
const
  AlphaChars=['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'];
begin
    case Step of
      1:If Email[I] in AlphaChars then
        Result := ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 2);
      2:If Email[I] in AlphaChars then
          Result := ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 2)
        else if Email[I] = '@' then
          Result := ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 3);
      3:If Email[I] in AlphaChars then
        Result := ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 4);
      4:If Email[I] in AlphaChars then
        Result := ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 4)
        else if Email[I]='.' then
          Result := ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 5);
      5:If Email[I] in AlphaChars then
        Result := ValidEmail(Email, I+1, 6);
      //6:
      else
        Result := True;
    end;
  end;
```

Note that this does not rely on any global variable - you could call ValidEmail recursively, along the lines of

```
Function ValidEmail(Email:string; I:integer; Step:integer):boolean;
const
  AlphaChars=['a'..'z', 'A'..'Z'];
begin
    case Step of
    ...
    7 : Result := ValidEmail(EMail, i, SomeOtherStep);
      else
        Result := True;
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: It should have the result explicitly set to False at the start for cases when the email isn't valid

Comment: @kbickar: This just to illustrate a specific point - it is not meant as production-quality code.

Comment: Also what is the advantage of using the second method you put or is the first method better? Thanks for the quick reply btw